# Which threading library does gcc on linux use to implement OpenMP?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, openmp

Does it use pthreads or some other threading API?

Comment: Implementation dependant, the standard does not actually say.  Most likely it will use 'native' threads.  For example on Windows it will use Win32 threads.

Comment: @cdarke, the questions asks for gcc on linux. (Not saying you're wrong, just off-topic.)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, gcc on linux uses pthreads.

Comment: ... via OpenMP support library named "libgomp". Which also uses some non-pthread primitives, like futex and atomic operations directly.

Answer (score 1):

it depends what you compile GCC with , standard linux implementations come with posix threads  for OpenMP , type `gcc -v` on terminal

here is the output from my laptop with the part of interest in bold

```
[n@N-pc-t61 ~]$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.6.3/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada,go,lto --enable-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch=i686 --build=i686-redhat-linux
**Thread model: posix**
```

here are all the available options from the gcc website

```
--enable-threads=lib
    Specify that lib is the thread support library. This affects the Objective-C compiler and runtime library, and exception handling for other languages like C++ and Java. The possibilities for lib are:

    aix
        AIX thread support.
    dce
        DCE thread support.
    lynx
        LynxOS thread support.
    mipssde
        MIPS SDE thread support.
    no
        This is an alias for `single'.
    posix
        Generic POSIX/Unix98 thread support.
    rtems
        RTEMS thread support.
    single
        Disable thread support, should work for all platforms.
    tpf
        TPF thread support.
    vxworks
        VxWorks thread support.
    win32
        Microsoft Win32 API thread support.
```

Comment: GCC always uses Pthreads for libgomp (the OpenMP runtime library), it doesn't depend on the Thread Model the rest of GCC uses.